# append_data deprecated in R (tmaptools package)

Tags: r, function, deprecated, tmap

I want to use `append_data` (tmaptools package), but appears a message that show:

*"This function is deprecated and has been migrated to github.com/mtennekes/oldtmaptoolsError in append_data(World, wbData4, key.shp = "iso_a3", key.data = "iso3c",  : 
  Data contains duplicated keys: NA. Set ignore.duplicates=TRUE to ignore duplicates in data."*

Is there any other function in tmaptools package (or in other package in CRAN) that replace that function?

Thanks!!

Comment: https://github.com/mtennekes/oldtmaptools/blob/43331a077f11400fa0195ea2c3539aca17ffb496/R/append_data.R#L27 implies that `dplyr::left_join` has the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Brian that helped me a lot!!